# Создание папки в репозитории на git

Tags: github, репозиторий

В репозитории на **git** уже загружены несколько проектов(файлы с расширением `.ipynb`). Но теперь хочу для каждого такого файла создать папку, в которой будет лежать сам проект и описание к нему в виде `README.md`

Как можно создать папку в репозитории и добавить в нее уже загруженный файл?

Comment: Судя по вопросу, у вас рудиментарные представления о гите. Поэтому надо прочитать хотя бы основы https://selectel.ru/blog/tutorials/git-setup-and-common-commands/

Answer (score 0):

Сначала все нужные действия(создание папок, перетаскивание файлов и т.д.) сделайте локально(т.е. на вашем ПК), потом в командной строке пропишите `git add .`, потом `git commit -m "commit comment"`, ну а потом загрузите изменения на удаленный репозиторий с помощью команды `git push`
А вообще в редакторах Pycharm, VS и других уже встроена система Git. Там с ней работать удобнее.